Why does my laptop restart when I attempt to run Strinova?
Every time I open Strinova (the global release version off Steam), my laptop restarts.
It let me make an account, which I did. It then brings me to a menu every time I open the game:

Every time I press start, my laptop restarts. It always lets me go to this menu though.
I've tried running it as an administrator too, but no fix. There's no change whether I run the game through a shortcut, through Steam, or though finding the .exe file and running that.
I’ve also tried running with the following start-up options in Steam

-dx11
-dx12
-d3d11

I checked the integrity of the game files through Steam, and it said everything was correct.
I also tried deleting/uninstalling the Steam game and downloading it from their official website, but the same thing happened (this resulted in the Windows Defender icon showing up on the game shortcut, but this is apparently because of a kernel-level anti-cheat; pc still restarted when running it).
Redownloading the game off Steam didn't fix it. I also tried getting Strinova off Epic Games, but the same problem happened.
(I currently have three instances of Strinova on my laptop - one from Steam, one from Epic, one from the website. I don’t know if that would break stuff?)
My Windows event viewer logs (Windows Logs > Application, right after running the Epic Games instance of Strinova:


And then the Custom Views > Administrative section, also right when running the instance:

The BugCheck event:

The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was: 0x0000018b (0x00000000000000c0, 0xffffffffc0000001, 0x4766634d000002f6, 0x00000000f0200000). A dump was saved in: C:\WINDOWS\Minidump\120424-21609-01.dmp. Report Id: 93d7dfaf-10b4-4389-b233-a70b43d2a8c3.

The analysis of the .dmp file using windbg:
SECURE_KERNEL_ERROR (18b)
The secure kernel has encountered a fatal error.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000000000c0
Arg2: ffffffffc0000001
Arg3: 4766634d000002f6
Arg4: 00000000f0200000

Debugging Details:


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
Value: 1640

Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
Value: 8663

Key  : Analysis.IO.Other.Mb
Value: 4

Key  : Analysis.IO.Read.Mb
Value: 1

Key  : Analysis.IO.Write.Mb
Value: 28

Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
Value: 703

Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
Value: 31111

Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
Value: 94

Key  : Analysis.Version.DbgEng
Value: 10.0.27725.1000

Key  : Analysis.Version.Description
Value: 10.2408.27.01 amd64fre

Key  : Analysis.Version.Ext
Value: 1.2408.27.1

Key  : Bugcheck.Code.LegacyAPI
Value: 0x18b

Key  : Bugcheck.Code.TargetModel
Value: 0x18b<br><br>
Key  : Dump.Attributes.AsUlong
Value: 1808

Key  : Dump.Attributes.DiagDataWrittenToHeader
Value: 1

Key  : Dump.Attributes.ErrorCode
Value: 0

Key  : Dump.Attributes.KernelGeneratedTriageDump
Value: 1

Key  : Dump.Attributes.LastLine
Value: Dump completed successfully.

Key  : Dump.Attributes.ProgressPercentage
Value: 0

Key  : Failure.Bucket
Value: SECURE_KERNEL_ERROR_c0_securekernel!SkhalpPciAccessDeviceInternal+0xf5_IMAGE_securekernelerror

Key  : Failure.Hash
Value: {14aac6cd-1371-34a0-f300-e4f2eb9d5d93}

Key  : Hypervisor.Enlightenments.ValueHex
Value: 7497cf94

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.AnyHypervisorPresent
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.ApicEnlightened
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.ApicVirtualizationAvailable
Value: 0

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.AsyncMemoryHint
Value: 0

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.CoreSchedulerRequested
Value: 0

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.CpuManager
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.DeprecateAutoEoi
Value: 0

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.DynamicCpuDisabled
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.Epf
Value: 0

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.ExtendedProcessorMasks
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.HardwareMbecAvailable
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.MaxBankNumber
Value: 0

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.MemoryZeroingControl
Value: 0

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.NoExtendedRangeFlush
Value: 0

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.NoNonArchCoreSharing
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.Phase0InitDone
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.PowerSchedulerQos
Value: 0

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.RootScheduler
Value: 0

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.SynicAvailable
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.UseQpcBias
Value: 0

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.Value
Value: 38408431

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.ValueHex
Value: 24a10ef

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.VpAssistPage
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.Flags.VsmAvailable
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.AccessStats
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.CrashdumpEnlightened
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.CreateVirtualProcessor
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.DisableHyperthreading
Value: 0

Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.HostTimelineSync
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.HypervisorDebuggingEnabled
Value: 0

Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.IsHyperV
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.LivedumpEnlightened
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.MapDeviceInterrupt
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.MceEnlightened
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.Nested
Value: 0

Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.StartLogicalProcessor
Value: 1

Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.Value
Value: 1015

Key  : Hypervisor.RootFlags.ValueHex
Value: 3f7


BUGCHECK_CODE:  18b

BUGCHECK_P1: c0

BUGCHECK_P2: ffffffffc0000001

BUGCHECK_P3: 4766634d000002f6

BUGCHECK_P4: f0200000

FILE_IN_CAB:  120424-21609-01.dmp

TAG_NOT_DEFINED_202b:  *** Unknown TAG in analysis list 202b


DUMP_FILE_ATTRIBUTES: 0x1808
Kernel Generated Triage Dump

FAULTING_THREAD:  ffff93839f5bb080

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)


BLACKBOXNTFS: 1 (!blackboxntfs)


BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)


BLACKBOXWINLOGON: 1

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

PROCESS_NAME:  Strinova-Win64

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffb901`58942ca8 fffff800`b71482ca     : 00000000`0000018b 
00000000`000000c0 ffffffff`c0000001 4766634d`000002f6 : 
nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffb901`58942cb0 fffff800`b7176801     : ffff9383`8a4eefb0 
fffff800`b718c356 ffffb901`58952340 ffffb901`58942d30 : 
nt!HvlSkCrashdumpCallbackRoutine+0x9a
ffffb901`58942cf0 fffff800`b7285ac2     : 00000000`00000100 
ffffb901`58942ef0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 
nt!KiProcessNMI+0xb1
ffffb901`58942d30 fffff800`b728582e     : 00000000`00000000 
00000000`00000100 ffffb901`58942ef0 00000000`00000000 : 
nt!KxNmiInterrupt+0x82
ffffb901`58942e70 fffff800`475f001c     : fffff800`b72750db 
00000000`00000000 fffff901`06c6e4c0 00000000`00000000 : 
nt!KiNmiInterrupt+0x26e
fffff901`06c6e298 fffff800`b72750db     : 00000000`00000000 
fffff901`06c6e4c0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 
0xfffff800`475f001c
fffff901`06c6e2a0 fffff800`b6ef1118     : 00000000`00000000 
ffffb901`5890b180 00000000`00000008 fffff800`b6e76499 : 
nt!HvlSwitchToVsmVtl1+0xab
fffff901`06c6e3e0 fffff800`b7051cda     : ffff2912`f414a786 
00000000`00000000 fffff901`06c6e539 fffff901`06c6e864 : 
nt!VslpEnterIumSecureMode+0x2b8
fffff901`06c6e4a0 fffff800`b6ef2210     : ffff2912`f414a746 
00000000`000000ff 000000a3`0001ea10 fffff901`06c6e864 : 
nt!VslAccessPciDevice+0xba
fffff901`06c6e580 fffff800`b7024247     : 00000000`00000050 
00000000`00000000 fffff901`06c6e864 00000000`00000002 : 
nt!HalpPCIConfig+0xe0
fffff901`06c6e640 fffff800`b702419d     : 00000000`00000000 
fffff901`06c6e759 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000002 : 
nt!HalpWritePCIConfig+0x57
fffff901`06c6e690 fffff800`b7097a5a     : 00000000`00000000 
fffff901`06c6e86c 00000000`00000001 fffff901`06c6f750 : 
nt!HalpSetPCIData+0xa5
fffff901`06c6e7b0 fffff800`851c768d     : ffff9383`00000000 
ffff9383`a4dd25f0 fffff901`06c6f750 ffff9383`a4f8ea60 : 
nt!HalSetBusDataByOffset+0xca
fffff901`06c6e830 ffff9383`00000000     : ffff9383`a4dd25f0 
fffff901`06c6f750 ffff9383`a4f8ea60 00000000`000000a8 : 
ACE_BASE+0x768d
fffff901`06c6e838 ffff9383`a4dd25f0     : fffff901`06c6f750 
ffff9383`a4f8ea60 00000000`000000a8 fffff901`00000002 : 
0xffff9383`00000000
fffff901`06c6e840 fffff901`06c6f750     : ffff9383`a4f8ea60 
00000000`000000a8 fffff901`00000002 ffff0000`00000100 : 
0xffff9383`a4dd25f0
fffff901`06c6e848 ffff9383`a4f8ea60     : 00000000`000000a8 
fffff901`00000002 ffff0000`00000100 00000000`00000000 : 
0xfffff901`06c6f750
fffff901`06c6e850 00000000`000000a8     : fffff901`00000002 
ffff0000`00000100 00000000`00000000 fffff901`00000003 : 
0xffff9383`a4f8ea60
fffff901`06c6e858 fffff901`00000002     : ffff0000`00000100 
00000000`00000000 fffff901`00000003 00000000`0431aefb : 0xa8
fffff901`06c6e860 ffff0000`00000100     : 00000000`00000000 
fffff901`00000003 00000000`0431aefb 00000000`0431aefb : 
0xfffff901`00000002
fffff901`06c6e868 00000000`00000000     : fffff901`00000003 
00000000`0431aefb 00000000`0431aefb 00000000`00000000 : 
0xffff0000`00000100

MODULE_NAME: securekernelerror

IMAGE_NAME:  securekernelerror

STACK_COMMAND:  .process /r /p 0xffff9383a2d5c080; .thread 0xffff93839f5bb080 ; kb

The Kernel-Power event:

The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.

I can also run other games which are probably more intensive (Elden Ring, RE2, The Division 2, etc) just fine.
My electrical circuit is stable.
Nothing is overclocked.
Specs (which fulfill the minimum/recommended specs on Steam):

Laptop is an EVOO gaming EG-LP7-BK
Windows 11

Most recent version


NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060

Drivers are up to date


AMD Ryzen 7 4800H with Radeon Graphics
16 gigs of RAM


A Reddit user suggests to "disable your anti-virus and check if your pc has [Secure Boot] enabled". Btw check your system requirements for the game here

Sounds like your PSU might be struggling to supply enough power to your PC. Does this problem also affect other games?

@Nolonar No, just this one.

@pinckerman The website said I should be able to run Strinova. I disabled the anti-virus for Strinova, no change. Secure boot is on (I don't want to turn it off though unless there are no other options).

The power supply comment is interesting.  Maybe run an artificial stress test on your cpu and/or gpu and see if your pc also trips off. If so, that could be it.  Also check windows event viewer for maybe some odd events going off.

@TimmyJim I added event viewer logs to the question. Nothing lists a source as strinova.exe though (strinova didn't come up anywhere).

Some of those errors in the second screenshot look interesting at least - namely the BugCheck one which looks to be just before the critical Kernel-Power event which is the event of the unexpected shutdown of your computer... if you click on these, it should show more details.  What does it say?

Only thing I found that is kind of related is https://answers.microsoft.com/zh-hans/windows/forum/all/win11-securekernelerror/f3af571e-6fa1-4200-a025-b9dc0bcefecd (you may need to translate the page to English).  Looks like someone had a similar issue with Valorant.  A Microsoft rep. replied to the thread with suggestions, perhaps try those out.  Other than that, I am thinking this is some odd PCI error.  It feels similar to an issue I had with God of War, which the only fix was hardware replacement. Hopefully thats not the case for you.

@TimmyJim I'll check the Microsoft page solutions when I get home. It's not bad if it's a hardware replacement issue though - I'll be building a PC by the end of the year anyway with all-new/high-end parts, which should fix it (if it's a hardware problem).

I just thought of another thing to try. Disable your RTX GPU through device manager, or specify you want the game executable to use your integrated graphics in nvidias settings. Your CPU has integrated graphics. If the game runs with your dedicated GPU disabled, you likely narrowed down the problem

@TimmyJim Didn’t work, unfortunately.
